# setTimeout function issue when called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a "setTimeout" issue when a function is called multiple times.

When a user clicks on .icon, a function is called which will hide the div for the duration set as the third array parameter, then show it.

It works fine unless one clicks on an item and then clicks on another one. In that case the duration is set to the last one clicked for both items. 
I tried to generate a random variable instead of var cooldowndata but it didn't worked.

Data-id has the following : name, price and "timeout" duration.

```
<div class="actions">
    <div class="actionholder">
        <div class="box"><div class="subbox"></div><div class="icon" data-id="ItemA|33|15000">ItemA 15s.</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="subbox"></div><div class="icon"  data-id="ItemB|21|6000">ItemB 6s.</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="subbox"></div><div class="icon"  data-id="ItemC|45|28000">ItemC 28s.</div></div>
    </div>
</div>

$(".icon").bind("click",function() {
var data = $(this).data("id");
cooldown(data);
});

function cooldown(data)
{
var cooldowndata =  data.split('|'); 
actiontohide = $("div").find("[data-id='" + data + "']");
actiontohide.hide();
setTimeout(function() { actiontohide.show(); }, cooldowndata[2]);
}
```

As a for instance you can start with item B then item C, C will show up after 6 seconds instead of 28 seconds: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xpqbccn3/

Any pointers would be highly appreciated in understanding what I did wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: atleast you should a working fiddle.

Comment: Which div are you trying to hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`actiontohide` is a global, so each click overwrites it.

```
actiontohide = $("div").find("[data-id='" + data + "']");
```

should be

```
var actiontohide = $("div").find("[data-id='" + data + "']");
```